# Showing that a map $F: X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^J$ is an embedding when $X$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

> Let X be a Hausdoroff space. Let $F = \{f_j : X \rightarrow \Bbb{R} | j \in J \}$ be a family of continuous real-valued functions with the following property: for every $x \in X$, and every closed set $A \subset X$ with $x \not\in A$, there exists $f_j \in F$ with $f_j(x) > 0$ and $f_j(a) = 0$ for every $a \in A$. (Such a family is said to separate points and closed sets.) Define $F : X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^J$ via $F(x) = (f_j(x))_{j \in J}$ . Show that $F$ is an embedding of $X$ into $\Bbb{R}^J$.

To show that $F$ is an embedding, we need to prove that $F: X \rightarrow F(X)$ is a homeomorphism with respect to the subspace topology.

F is obviously continuous by the universal mapping property for the product topology. It is also obviously surjective, since the target is $F(X)$.

Let $F(a) = F(b)$ for some $a,b \in X$. Then $f_j(a) = f_j(b)$ for all $j \in J$. Suppose for contradiction that $a \not= b$. This means that for $a \in X$, and the closed set $\{b\}$, there exists $i \in J$ such that $f_i(a) > 0$ and $f_i (b) = 0$. A contradiction.

Now I need to show that $F$ is open, but I'm not sure how. Can anybody give me a hint so I can get started?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try showing $f: X \rightarrow f[X]$ is a closed map.

So let $A \subset X$ be closed, and suppose $y \in f[X]$ is such that $y \notin f[A]$.
We need to show that there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $y$ that does not intersect $f[A]$. This will show that $f[A]$ is closed in $f[X]$.

We have $x \in X$ with $y = f(x)$, and we know that $x \notin A$. Now apply the assumption on the family $(f_j)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the assumption on the family $(f_j)$, we know that there exists $f_i$ with $f_i(x)>0$ and $f_i(a)=0$ for $a \in A$· But then $(U_j)_{j \in J}$ with $U_j=f_j(X)$ for all $j  \in J$ such that $i \not= j$ and $U_i = \Bbb{R}-\{0\}$ is an open neighborhood for $y$ which does not intersect $f(A)$, right?

Comment: I'd take $U_j = \mathbb{R}$ for $i \neq j$ (as $f_j[X]$ need not be open). Then suppose $f(a) \in f[A]$, then $f(a)_i = f_i(a) = 0$ so $f(a) \notin \prod_j U_j$ as required, indeed.

Comment: Thanks, but we are trying to show that $f:X \rightarrow f[X]$ is a homeomorphism, right? So doesn't the definition of the subspace topology tell us that $\Bbb{R} \cap f_j[X] =f_j[X]$ is open?

Comment: $f_j[X]$ need not be open in $\mathbb{R}$, and neither is $f[X]$ open in the product. We only know that if $A$ is closed in $X$, then $f[A]$ is closed in $f[X]$. And similarly for open.